# Column wise specific value count

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matrix, arraylist

```
aMat=df1000.iloc[:,1:].values
print(aMat)
```

By using the above code I got the below mentioned data matrix from a dataset:

```
[[1 2 5 2 4]
 [1 2 1 2 2]
 [1 2 4 2 4]
 [1 5 1 1 4]
 [1 4 4 2 5]]
```

The data set only can hold 1,2,3,4 and 5 value. So I want to count number of 1 present in first column, number of 2 present in first column, number of 3 present in first column, number of 4 present in first column, number of 5 present in first column, number of 1 present in second column,.............so on. Means at the end the list will look like this:

```
[[5,0,0,0,0],[0,3,0,1,1],[2,0,0,2,5],[1,4,0,0,0],[0,1,0,3,1]]
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My attempt with `get_dummies` and `sum`:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).sum(level=1)

   1  2  4  5
0  5  0  0  0
1  0  3  1  1
2  2  0  2  1
3  1  4  0  0
4  0  1  3  1
```

If you need the column 3 with all zeros, use `reindex`:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).sum(level=1).reindex(columns=range(1, 6), fill_value=0)

   1  2  3  4  5
0  5  0  0  0  0
1  0  3  0  1  1
2  2  0  0  2  1
3  1  4  0  0  0
4  0  1  0  3  1
```

---

Or, if you fancy a main course of numpy with a side dish of broadcasting:

```
# edit courtesy @user3483203
np.equal.outer(df.values, np.arange(1, 6)).sum(0)

array([[5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0, 1, 1],
       [2, 0, 0, 2, 1],
       [1, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 3, 1]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 5, 2, 4],
 [1, 2, 1, 2, 2],
 [1, 2, 4, 2, 4],
 [1, 5, 1, 1, 4],
 [1, 4, 4, 2, 5]])

df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).reindex([1,2,3,4,5]).fillna(0).to_numpy('int')
```

Output:

```
array([[5, 0, 2, 1, 0],
       [0, 3, 0, 4, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 0, 3],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Or, transposed:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).reindex([1,2,3,4,5]).fillna(0).T.to_numpy('int')
```

Output:

```
array([[5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0, 1, 1],
       [2, 0, 0, 2, 1],
       [1, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 3, 1]])
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'apply' this error is showing after applying the code

Comment: Or remove the .values from `aMat=df1000.iloc[:,1:]`

Comment: Reindex with `range` instead of `[1,2,3,4,5]`, it's a little cleaner. +1

Answer (score 3):

You can use `np.bincount` with `apply_along_axis`.

```
a = df.to_numpy()
np.apply_along_axis(np.bincount, 0, a, minlength=a.max()+1).T[:, 1:]
```

```
array([[5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 3, 0, 1, 1],
       [2, 0, 0, 2, 1],
       [1, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 3, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 3):

May using `stack`

```
df.stack().groupby(level=1).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0).reindex(columns=[1,2,3,4,5],fill_value=0)
Out[495]: 
   1  2  3  4  5
0  5  0  0  0  0
1  0  3  0  1  1
2  2  0  0  2  1
3  1  4  0  0  0
4  0  1  0  3  1
```

---

Method from `collections`

```
pd.DataFrame(list(map(collections.Counter,a.T))).fillna(0)#.values
Out[527]: 
     1    2    4    5
0  5.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  3.0  1.0  1.0
2  2.0  0.0  2.0  1.0
3  1.0  4.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  1.0  3.0  1.0
```